# How to avoid recompiling in this cabal file?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I've been working on this Haskell project, and I have a cabal file for it. Now, my project is structured as a library that implements a simple interpreter. I also have a very short Main file which needs to be build into an executable to call the library. What I want to do is:

1) compile the library and expose some of the modules

2) compile the executable

I have a cabal file that works and seems to do this. The problem is that when it compiles the executable it *recompiles all the modules which have already been compiled in step (1)*. I don't quite understand why it does this - is there any way to stop it, short of creating two separate cabal files?

I don't really want to create two separate cabal files, because cabal doesn't seem to like having both the cabal files in the same directory, and I don't really want to set up a separate project directory for the second step, since it basically just amounts to compiling a single file.

```
cabal-version:      >= 1.6
build-type:         Simple
name:               HaSC
version:            0.2.3
license:            OtherLicense
category:           Language
author:             Chris B
maintainer:         Chris B
copyright:          Chris B 2010 - 2011
synopsis:           (HA)skell (S)ound (C)hange applier (HaSC) library
description:        HaSC implements a little language for applying sound changes to words
homepage:           http://www.chrisdb.me.uk/redmine/projects/haskell-sound-change
stability:          Alpha
data-files:         doc/HaSCDoc.pdf
license-file:       LICENSE

library
    build-depends:
        base >= 4.3,
        containers >= 0.3,
        parsec >= 3,
        parallel >= 3.1,
        deepseq >= 1.1,
        mtl >= 1.1, 
        transformers >= 0.2,
        text >= 0.10,
        text-icu >= 0.6.3,
        pretty >= 1,
        directory >= 1.1,
        filepath >= 1.2
    hs-source-dirs:  src
    exposed-modules: HaSC.IO.Disk,
                     HaSC.IO.Memory,
                     HaSC.Exec
    other-modules:   HaSC.AST,
                     HaSC.IO,
                     HaSC.IdentMap,
                     HaSC.Parse,
                     HaSC.Regex,
                     HaSC.Representation,                     
                     HaSC.Transformations,
                     HaSC.Search,
                     HaSC.State

executable HaSC
    GHC-Options: -rtsopts
    hs-source-dirs:  src
    main-is:         Main.hs
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your executable section, add the library in `Build-Depends` so that the executable depends on the library.

There's a small gotcha, though: You also have to move the `Main.hs` of the executable (and any other source files specific to the executable) to a different subdirectory and specify a different `Hs-Source-Dirs` so that it doesn't pick up the library modules by being in the same folder.

```
executable HaSC
    Build-Depends: HaSC
    Main-Is: Main.hs
    Hs-Source-Dirs: foo -- Directory you moved Main.hs to
```

For this to work, you will need to specify `Cabal-Version >= 1.8`. See [Cabal ticket #89](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/hackage/ticket/89) for the details.

Comment: Ah, this how one makes executables depend on the library in the same cabal file.

Comment: For a possible project layout fitting situations like this, see [How to make a Haskell cabal project with library+executables that still run with runhaskell/ghci?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305970/how-to-make-a-haskell-cabal-project-with-libraryexecutables-that-still-run-with).

Comment: I wish I could up-vote the answer more than once.  The "gotcha" is key and was killing me.  Thanks.