# How to make a Haskell cabal project with library+executables that still run with runhaskell/ghci?

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci, runhaskell

If you [declare a library + executable sections in a cabal file while avoiding double compilation of the library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711151/how-to-avoid-recompiling-in-this-cabal-file/6711739) by putting the library into a `hs-source-dirs` directory, you cannot usually run your project with `ghci` and `runhaskell` anymore, especially if the executables have helper modules themselves.

What is a recommended project layout that

- only builds what is needed once
- allows using `runhaskell`
- has a clean structure without hacks?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Let's assume you have a `mylib` library, and `mylib-commandline` and `mylib-server` executables.

You use `hs-source-dirs` for the library and each executable so that each has their own project root, avoiding double compilation:

```
mylib/                      # Project root
  mylib.cabal
  src/                      # Root for the library
  tests/
  mylib-commandline/        # Root for the command line utility + helper modules
  mylib-server/             # Root for the web service + helper modules
```

Full directory layout:

```
mylib/                      # Project root
  mylib.cabal
  src/                      # Root for the library
    Web/
      Mylib.hs              # Main library module
      Mylib/
        ModuleA             # Mylib.ModuleA
        ModuleB             # Mylib.ModuleB
  tests/
    ...
  mylib-commandline/        # Root for the command line utility
    Main.hs                 # "module Main where" stub with "main = Web.Mylib.Commandline.Main.main"
    Web/
      Mylib/
        Commandline/
          Main.hs           # CLI entry point
          Arguments.hs      # Programm command line arguments parser
  mylib-server/             # Root for the web service
    Server.hs               # "module Main where" stub with "main = Web.Mylib.Server.Main.main"
    Web/
      Mylib/
        Server/
          Main.hs           # Server entry point
          Arguments.hs      # Server command line arguments parser
```

The *stub-like* entry point file `mylib-commandline/Main.hs` looks like this:

```
module Main where

import qualified Web.Mylib.Server.Main as MylibServer

main :: IO ()
main = MylibServer.main
```

You need them because an `executable` must start on a module simply called `Main`.

Your `mylib.cabal` looks like this:

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:   src
  exposed-modules:
    Web.Mylib
    Web.Mylib.ModuleA
    Web.Mylib.ModuleB
  build-depends:
      base >= 4 && <= 5
    , [other dependencies of the library]

executable mylib-commandline
  hs-source-dirs:   mylib-commandline
  main-is:          Main.hs
  other-modules:
    Web.Mylib.Commandline.Main
    Web.Mylib.Commandline.Arguments
  build-depends:
      base >= 4 && <= 5
    , mylib
    , [other depencencies for the CLI]

executable mylib-server
  hs-source-dirs:   mylib-server
  main-is:          Server.hs
  other-modules:
    Web.Mylib.Server.Main
  build-depends:
      base >= 4 && <= 5
    , mylib
    , warp >= X.X
    , [other dependencies for the server]
```

`cabal build` will build the library and the two executables without double compilation of the library, because each is in their own `hs-source-dirs` and the executables depend on the library.

You can still run the executables with `runghc` from your project root, using the `-i` switch to tell where it shall look for modules (using `:` as separator):

```
runhaskell -isrc:mylib-commandline mylib-commandline/Main.hs

runhaskell -isrc:mylib-server mylib-server/Server.hs
```

This way, you can have a clean layout, executables with helper modules, and everything still works with `runhaskell`/`runghc` and `ghci`. To avoid typing this flag repeatedly, you can add something similar to

```
:set -isrc:mylib-commandline:mylib-server
```

to your `.ghci` file.

---

Note that sometimes should split your code into separate packages, e.g. `mylib`, `mylib-commandline` and `mylib-server`.

Comment: Perfect answer, I was looking for such simple and straightforward article on official Haskell Pages but with no luck. Probably I did not spend enough time searching but this helped me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cabal repl` to start ghci with the configuration from the cabal file and `cabal run` to compile and run the executables. Unlike `runhaskell` and `ghci`, using `cabal repl` and `cabal run` also picks up dependencies from cabal sandboxes correctly.