# Haskell cabal build undefined reference error and duplicate recompilation

Tags: haskell, cabal

My question comes in two parts. The first is that when I compile my project I get a long list of errors of the form

```
  (.text+0x137f): undefined reference to `raytrzuAd6RComi0WmBiuT4685WWH_Types_zdfBinaryColor_closure'
```

The full list of errors can be found [here](http://lpaste.net/138988)
The code that produces this error can be found [here](https://github.com/jrraymond/ray-tracer/tree/master).

I am using ghc 7.10.1 and cabal 1.22.4.0.

The second part of my question is that despite following the same cabal structure as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305970/how-to-make-a-haskell-cabal-project-with-libraryexecutables-that-still-run-with), cabal still recompiles the library 3 times each cabal build despite the executables and the library all having a unique `hs-source-dir` and depending on the library.

EDIT: as far as the triple compilation is concerned, the first time it builds `.o` files `[ 2 of 15] Compiling Types            ( src/Types.hs, dist/build/Types.o )`. The second time it builds `.p_o` files `[ 2 of 15] Compiling Types            ( src/Types.hs, dist/build/Types.p_o )` which are caused by TemplateHaskell and profiling.

Comment: You should include all the other non-exported modules in your Cabal file in the `other-modules` field – does that fix your linking problem?  (I can't test myself as I'm still on 7.8.3, so I can't build your code.)

Comment: It looks like that fixes the undefined reference problem works <3 <3 <3.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky as this resolved the problem, you should post it as an answer :-)

Comment: @sclv: Good point :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should include all the other non-exported modules in your Cabal file in the `other-modules` field, otherwise they won't be linked in properly when producing the final library or executable.

You can see [the Cabal User's Guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#modules-included-in-the-package) for more information (although that pretty much sums up the situation with `other-modules`!).

Comment: First of all, sorry for posting this into a comment, but I ran into a similar situation as the questioner. I'm using an external library called **gstreamer** for the haskell package **haskell-gi**. Now the linker runs into several **undefined reference**' problems. Example: **"undefined reference to `g_irepository_require'"** . This method is part of a .c or .h file, that is called gi-repository.c / gi-repository.h. I have looked through Cabals' User Guide but still don't have a clue how to add that file to **"other-modules"**. Could you give me an example?

Comment: @oRole: Since that's a C function, you handle it differently – this answer deals specifically with Haskell code.  I don't have a quick answer, so you should [ask a new question!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :-)

Comment: Thank you anyways!