# Could not find module `Data.Map' -- It is a member of the hidden package

Tags: haskell, import, module, haskell-stack

First, I created a new workspace:

```
stack new xxxx
stack init
stack build
```

then

```
cd xxx\app
stack ghci
import Data.Map
```

I can import other modules like `Data.Char` and `Data.List`, but I can't import `Data.Map`. GHCi told me:

```
Could not find module 'Data.Map'
 It is a member of the hidden package 'containers-0.5.7.1@containers-0.5.7.1'.`
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason you can import `Data.Char` and `Data.List` is that they are part of the package `base`, which is included with GHC and is always loaded with GHCi. By contrast, `Data.Map` is in the external library `containers`. One way to load it with `stack ghci` is to add a cabal file with a `build-depends` on `containers`. This will install it in the stack environment for `xxxx`, so it will then be accessible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Create a cabal file `xxxx.cabal`, add a library/executable section, and add `containers` in the `build-depends` section. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12305972/925978).

Answer (score 46):

[These general steps](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/wiki/New-to-Haskell#general-usage) were helpful for me to resolve similar issues:

1. **Use [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) or [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/) to find the package where the module resides**

   Note that [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/) are *case-sensitive*. Looking up `Data.Map` in [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) yields a list similar to the one below. [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/) has a slightly different style, but the basics are the same (mostly because it also uses Hoogle for lookup).

The lines in green under the result headings show the name(s) of the containing

(1) package(s) (in small caps) and

(2) module(s) (capitalized).

[image: Hoogle result for Data.Map]

2. **Open** `project-name.cabal` **in project root and add required package under** `build-depends:`

   ```
   library
     hs-source-dirs:
         src

     build-depends:
         base >= 4.7 && < 5
       , containers

     exposed-modules:
         Lib
   ```
3. **Issue** `stack build` **to download and build dependencies**

   (or `stack ghci` if you plan to use it in the REPL)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! (the previous answer "gave me a fish" instead of "showing me how to fish")

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks a lot for the edit! I just realized how inaccessible it was with the image...

Comment: @toraritte, you're welcome. Hopefully we'll be able to make some progress towards accessibility.

Comment: I put `containers` to package.yaml file, under library-> dependencies, and it worked

Answer (score 5):

I my case I had to add `containers` to `package.yaml` instead of adding the dependency directly to the `.cabal` file:

```
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- containers
```