# Why is `stack build` altering my .cabal file?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, euterpea

I am attempting to build a project which uses [Euterpea](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Euterpea-2.0.2/docs/Euterpea.html).

Running `stack build` I get the following error, suggesting that I need to add `Euterpea` to the `build-depends` section of my `.cabal` file.

```
$ sb
composition-0.1.0.0: build (lib + exe)
Preprocessing library composition-0.1.0.0...
[2 of 2] Compiling Lib              ( src/Lib.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Lib.o )

/home/matthew/backup/composition/composition/src/Lib.hs:5:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Euterpea’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘Euterpea-2.0.4’.
    Perhaps you need to add ‘Euterpea’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

--  While building package composition-0.1.0.0 using:
      /home/matthew/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build lib:composition exe:composition-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I add `Euterpea` there, and the `library` section of my `.cabal` file then is the following.

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:
      src
  build-depends:   base >= 4.7 && < 5
                 , Euterpea
  exposed-modules:
      Lib
  other-modules:
      Paths_composition
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

However, when I then run `stack build` again, it gives the same error -- and changes my `.cabal` file back to what it was originally, with the `library` section then looking like

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:
      src
  build-depends:
      base >= 4.7 && < 5
  exposed-modules:
      Lib
  other-modules:
      Paths_composition
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

Why is `stack build` altering my `cabal` file? I have never seen that occurring before.

---

Side note:
Not sure if it is related, but the `.cabal` file's format appears to be different than it normally does. Here as with previous projects I auto-initialized by running `stack new <project-name>`. I don't know what I might have done different from previous projects to cause this unexpected behavior of `stack build`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure `package.yaml` exists in the root of your project directory.

`package.yaml` is a new file format to improve the syntax of cabal, converted by [hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack).

Stack supports hpack as strongly as the `stack build` command automatically converts package.yaml into a cabal file with `hpack` command.

So, delete `package.yaml` or edit `package.yaml` to add Euterpea package.
Editing it would not be so difficult as its format is YAML.

Comment: Oh wow this really helps to explain the last few minutes of my life!

Answer (score 2):

I want to add to the [YAMAMOTO Yuji's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4299824/yamamoto-yuji) answer. The solution is absolutely right. But I just wanted to add few things, it is not hard to edit the `package.yaml`.

**Step 1** : The trickiest part is **finding the correct package name**.

> Use [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) or [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/) to find the package where the module
> resides. Read more about how to find package name in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49291575/7350753).

**Step 2** : Now you have to open the package.yaml file and add the package name. In your case add *'Euterpea'* package in the list of dependencies.

```
dependencies:
...
- your-package-name
```

> Please note that **Euterpea** package has to be added in a different way. Please read [this
> post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49291575/7350753) for better understanding.

**Step 3** : Open `project-name.cabal` in project root and add required package name under `build-depends`:

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:
      src

  build-depends:
      base >= 4.7 && < 5
    , your-package-name

  exposed-modules:
      Lib
```

**Step 4** :Issue `stack build` to download and build dependencies
(or `stack ghci` if you plan to use it in the *REPL*)

Hope this works! Happy coding! :)

Comment: This last answer is similar to what I ended up doing to fix this problem. Had to edit both package.yaml and the project .cabal file. I learned that some package names, both as they are in Hackage and in these two files, will be lower case (text, hspec), while others are not (QuickCheck).