# How to find a Haskell function based on its type signature?

Tags: haskell

For example, I haven't used Haskell in a while, and forgot the name of the `const` function, but remembered that its type signature is `a -> b -> a`.

Answer (score 11):

Use [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org) or [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org). (See also [related Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49291575/1498178).)

<sup>As far as I know, Stackage uses Hoogle underneath, but one may find its representation easier to read.</sup>

Just type any type signature that would be acceptable by Haskell, and browse the results.