# Compile Haskell program with third-party dependencies

Tags: haskell, package, cabal

I am trying to jump into some Haskell again after being away for a while. One piece of code I wrote ages ago inclues `import qualified Data.MultiMap as MultiMap`. Since `Data.MultipMap` is in the `containers` package, I get errors when I just run `ghc program.hs`. I've attempted to write a `project.cabal` file based on [How to make a Haskell cabal project with library+executables that still run with runhaskell/ghci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305970/how-to-make-a-haskell-cabal-project-with-libraryexecutables-that-still-run-with/12305972#12305972). My latest attempt is

```
name: project
version: 1.0
executable project
    main-is: project.hs
    build-dependencies:
        base >= 4 && <= 5
      , containers
```

Now when I do `cabal build project`, I get

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: project-1.0 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: project:setup.Cabal (dependency of project)
[__1] rejecting: project:setup.Cabal-3.4.0.0/installed-3.4.0.0 (conflict:
project => project:setup.Cabal>=1.0 && <1.25)
[__1] skipping: project:setup.Cabal-3.4.0.0, project:setup.Cabal-3.2.1.0,
project:setup.Cabal-3.2.0.0, project:setup.Cabal-3.0.2.0,
project:setup.Cabal-3.0.1.0, project:setup.Cabal-3.0.0.0,
project:setup.Cabal-2.4.1.0, project:setup.Cabal-2.4.0.1,
project:setup.Cabal-2.4.0.0, project:setup.Cabal-2.2.0.1,
project:setup.Cabal-2.2.0.0, project:setup.Cabal-2.0.1.1,
project:setup.Cabal-2.0.1.0, project:setup.Cabal-2.0.0.2 (has the same
characteristics that caused the previous version to fail: excluded by
constraint '>=1.0 && <1.25' from 'project')
[__1] rejecting: project:setup.Cabal-1.24.2.0, project:setup.Cabal-1.24.0.0,
project:setup.Cabal-1.22.8.0, project:setup.Cabal-1.22.7.0,
project:setup.Cabal-1.22.6.0, project:setup.Cabal-1.22.5.0,
project:setup.Cabal-1.22.4.0, project:setup.Cabal-1.22.3.0,
project:setup.Cabal-1.22.2.0, project:setup.Cabal-1.22.1.1,
project:setup.Cabal-1.22.1.0, project:setup.Cabal-1.22.0.0,
project:setup.Cabal-1.20.0.4, project:setup.Cabal-1.20.0.3,
project:setup.Cabal-1.20.0.2, project:setup.Cabal-1.20.0.1,
project:setup.Cabal-1.20.0.0, project:setup.Cabal-1.18.1.7,
project:setup.Cabal-1.18.1.6, project:setup.Cabal-1.18.1.5,
project:setup.Cabal-1.18.1.4, project:setup.Cabal-1.18.1.3,
project:setup.Cabal-1.18.1.2, project:setup.Cabal-1.18.1.1,
project:setup.Cabal-1.18.1, project:setup.Cabal-1.18.0,
project:setup.Cabal-1.16.0.3, project:setup.Cabal-1.16.0.2,
project:setup.Cabal-1.16.0.1, project:setup.Cabal-1.16.0,
project:setup.Cabal-1.14.0, project:setup.Cabal-1.12.0,
project:setup.Cabal-1.10.2.0, project:setup.Cabal-1.10.1.0,
project:setup.Cabal-1.10.0.0, project:setup.Cabal-1.8.0.6,
project:setup.Cabal-1.8.0.4, project:setup.Cabal-1.8.0.2,
project:setup.Cabal-1.6.0.3, project:setup.Cabal-1.6.0.2,
project:setup.Cabal-1.6.0.1, project:setup.Cabal-1.4.0.2,
project:setup.Cabal-1.4.0.1, project:setup.Cabal-1.4.0.0,
project:setup.Cabal-1.2.4.0, project:setup.Cabal-1.2.3.0,
project:setup.Cabal-1.2.2.0, project:setup.Cabal-1.2.1,
project:setup.Cabal-1.1.6, project:setup.Cabal-1.24.1.0 (constraint from
minimum version of Cabal used by Setup.hs requires >=3.4)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: project, project:setup.Cabal)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: project:setup.Cabal, project
```

What am I missing to get this to work? What should I do to compile my Haskell program?

Answer (score 2):

Change your `project.cabal` to:

```
cabal-version: 3.4
name: project
version: 1.0
executable project
    main-is: project.hs
    build-depends:
        base >= 4 && <= 5
      , multimap
```

`cabal-version: 3.4` picks the latest version of the Cabal package format, which should be fine to use given that you are using Cabal 3.4 already. Left unspecified, `cabal-version` defaults to a very old version (as in recent versions [the field is mandatory](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-package.html#pkg-field-cabal-version)), which makes [the `build-type` field](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-package.html#pkg-field-build-type) default to `Custom` rather than `Simple`. That, in turn, leads to the error you got, as described in [cabal issue #5278](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/5278). In addition, I have changed `build-dependencies` to `build-depends`, and `containers` to `multimap` (as [the latter package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multimap) is the one that provides `Data.MultiMap`).

Comment: Thanks. At the end of the day I ended up doing `cabal install --lib multimap` and was able to continue from there. I had previously installed `containers` and was still getting compiler errors.