# One multimode Haskell executable vs separate executables sharing a library

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm working on a project now in which I configure the cabal file to build several executables which share the library built by the same cabal file. The cabal project is structured much like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711151/how-to-avoid-recompiling-in-this-cabal-file/6711739), with one `library` section followed by several `executable` sections that include this library in their `build-depends` sections.

I'm using this approach so I can make common functions available to any number of executables, and create more executables easily as needed.

Yet in his [Monad Reader article on Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/f/f0/TMR-Issue12.pdf) p.33, Neil Mitchell advocates bundling up Haskell projects into a single executable with multiple modes (e.g. by using Neil Mitchell's CmdArgs library.) So there might be one mode to start a web server, another mode to query the database from the command line, etc. Quote:

> Provide one executable
>
> Version 3 had four executable programs – one to generate ranking
>   information, one to do command line searching, one to do web
>   searching, and one to do regression testing. Version 4 has one
>   executable, which does all the above and more, controlled by ﬂags.
>   There are many advantages to providing only one end program – it
>   reduces the chance of code breaking without noticing it, it makes the
>   total ﬁle size smaller by not duplicating the Haskell run-time system,
>   it decreases the number of commands users need to learn. The move to
>   one multipurpose executable seems to be a common theme, which tools
>   such as darcs and hpc both being based on one command with multiple
>   modes.

Is a single multimode executable really the better way to go? Are there countervailing reasons to stick with separate executables sharing the same library?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'm more of a fan of the Unix philosophy "write programs that do one thing and do it well". However there are reasons for doing either way, so the only reasonable answer here is: it depends.

One example where it makes senses to bundle everything into same executable, is when you're targeting a platform that is very limited on resources (e.g, embedded system). This is the approach taken by [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/).

On the other hand if you divide into multiple executables, you give your clients the option of just using those that matter to them. With a single executable, even if your client really just wanted one functionality, he'll have no way to get rid of the extra baggage.

I'm sure there are a lot of more reasons for going either way, but this just goes to show that there's no definitive answer. It depends on the use case.