# Build dependency in library or executable section of cabal file?

Tags: haskell, cabal

First off, I'm new to using cabal and external packages with Haskell.

I'm trying to use the Graphics.Gloss package inside of MyLib. I can make it work if I include `gloss` in both the `build-depends` of `library` and `executable`.

Here is the relevant portion of the cabal file:

```
library
  exposed-modules:     MyLib
  build-depends:       base ^>=4.13.0.0,
                       gloss ^>=1.13.1.1
  default-language:    Haskell2010

executable ray-tracer
  main-is:             Main.hs
  other-modules:       MyLib
  build-depends:       base ^>=4.13.0.0, ray-tracer,
                       haskell-say ^>=1.0.0.0,
                       gloss ^>=1.13.1.1
```

MyLib.hs

```
module MyLib (someFunc) where
import Graphics.Gloss

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = display (InWindow "My Window" (200,200) (10,10)) white (Circle 80)
```

Main.hs

```
module Main where

import qualified MyLib (someFunc)
import HaskellSay (haskellSay)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  MyLib.someFunc
```

Why doesn't this work when `gloss` is only included in the `library` dependencies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make it work. There is a problem in your current set up, which is that the files for the library and the executable are in the same directory. See also this question [How to avoid recompiling in this cabal file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711151/how-to-avoid-recompiling-in-this-cabal-file) which is a symptom of the same underlying problem: when you build the executable, it rebuilds `MyLib` from scratch (which requires the gloss dependency) instead of reusing your library that was already built.

```
MyLib/
  ray-tracer.cabal
  MyLib.hs
  Main.hs       # Bad
```

Move the `.hs` files in separate directories (technically you only need to move one of them, but I think it's better to keep the root directory as uniform as possible):

```
MyLib/
  MyLib.cabal
  src/
    MyLib.hs
  exe/
    Main.hs
```

And in the cabal file, add `hs-source-dirs: src` and `hs-source-dirs: exe` to the corresponding sections:

```
library
  hs-source-dirs: src
  ...

executable ray-tracer
  hs-source-dirs: exe
  ...
```