# How to avoid listing A as build dependency for internal library/executable E just because E depends on internal library L which depends on A?

Tags: haskell, linker, dependency-management, cabal

I have a directory structure like this

```
.
├── Main.hs
├── mynot.cabal
├── Notification.hs
└── Server.hs
```

where `mynot.cabal` looks like this

```
cabal-version:   3.0
name:            mynot
version:         0.1.0.0

common common
    default-language: GHC2021
    build-depends: base

executable mynot
    import: common
    main-is: Main.hs
    build-depends: dbus
                 , async
                 , containers
                 , extra
                 , flow
    other-modules: Server
                 , Notification

library server
    import: common
    exposed-modules: Server
    build-depends: async
                 , containers
                 , dbus
                 , extra
                 , flow
    other-modules: Notification

library notification
    import: common
    exposed-modules: Notification
    build-depends: containers
                 , dbus
                 , extra
```

but `extra` is really only needed by `Notification.hs`, and I have no clue why I need to list it also under the other stanzas for `cabal build` to succeed.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62286703/build-dependency-in-library-or-executable-section-of-cabal-file), and gave it a try, e.g via

```
$ mkdir exe
$ mv Main.hs exe/.
```

and then adding `hs-source-dirs: exe` in the `executable` stanza, but the build fails like this

```
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-9.4.8 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - mynot-0.1.0.0 (exe:mynot) (configuration changed)
 - mynot-0.1.0.0 (lib:notification) (configuration changed)
 - mynot-0.1.0.0 (lib:server) (configuration changed)
Configuring executable 'mynot' for mynot-0.1.0.0..
Configuring library 'notification' for mynot-0.1.0.0..
Configuring library 'server' for mynot-0.1.0.0..
Preprocessing library 'notification' for mynot-0.1.0.0..
Building library 'notification' for mynot-0.1.0.0..
Preprocessing executable 'mynot' for mynot-0.1.0.0..
Error: cabal-3.10.2.1: can't find source for Server in exe,
/home/enrico/mynot/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-9.4.8/mynot-0.1.0.0/x/mynot/build/mynot/autogen,
/home/enrico/mynot/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-9.4.8/mynot-0.1.0.0/x/mynot/build/global-autogen

Preprocessing library 'server' for mynot-0.1.0.0..
Building library 'server' for mynot-0.1.0.0..
Error: cabal: Failed to build exe:mynot from mynot-0.1.0.0.
```

Is something *wrong* with my project or just something *missing* in it?

Comment: In case it is usefull. I wrote a [quick review](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/9214#issuecomment-1694674261) of cabal's main concepts. I think you are confused by components and dependencies. Notice the guide is imprecise, and not official. So don't take it as a "gold resource"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a different `hs-source-dirs` then that will also influence where cabal will look for the `other-modules`.

Instead of using `other-modules` like that, you should [add the components to each others `build-depends` like this](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-package-description-file.html#pkg-field-build-depends):

```
executable mynot
    import: common
    main-is: Main.hs
    build-depends: dbus
                 , async
                 , containers
                 , flow
                 , mynot:server
                 , mynot:notification
    hs-source-dirs: exe

library server
    import: common
    exposed-modules: Server
    build-depends: async
                 , containers
                 , dbus
                 , flow
                 , mynot:notification
    hs-source-dirs: server

library notification
    import: common
    exposed-modules: Notification
    build-depends: containers
                 , dbus
                 , extra
    hs-source-dirs: notification
```

And you do apparently need to create directories for each component, so the file structure should look like this:

```
.
├── exe/Main.hs
├── mynot.cabal
├── notification/Notification.hs
└── server/Server.hs
```

Of course you can use different names for the directories if you change the `hs-source-dirs` fields too.

Generally, you want each module to be listed in only a single component. Otherwise each component will rebuild that module separately.

Comment: But where's `hs-source-dirs` defined now? Or are you suggesting not to move files in different subdirectories?

Comment: If I substitute this snippet as is to mine (well, to the part after my `common` stanza), `cabal build` fails with `Could not load module ‘Data.Tuple.Extra’` on `Notification.hs`. If I add `, extra` back to both `library server` and `executable mynot` stanzas, then the compilation succeeds, but that means I'm back to where I was, with just `mynot:` added on 3 lines instead of `other-modules:`.

Comment: It could be that it is indeed necessary to move all the components into separate directories and add `hs-source-dirs` to avoid each component grabbing the `Notification.hs` directly. I'll update my answer.