# Exposing internal modules to tests in Cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm contributing to an [open source project](https://github.com/jason-johnson/hodatime) which defines its project setup in a [cabal file](https://github.com/jason-johnson/hodatime/blob/master/hodatime.cabal) that looks like this (omitting lots of properties that are not relevant for this problem):

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:    src
  build-depends:
                     base >= 4.9 && < 5,
                     some-other-deps
  exposed-modules:
                     Data.Foo.Bar,
                     Data.Foo.Baz
  other-modules:
                     Data.Foo.Bar.Internal

test-suite test
  hs-source-dirs:
                     tests
  build-depends:
                     foo-library
  other-modules:
                     Foo.Bar.Tests,
                     Foo.Baz.Tests
```

Now, in order to test the feature I'm adding, I want the tests to have access to the `Data.Foo.Bar.Internal` module, but since it's hidden in the library, I can't access it from the tests.

I looked at the [cabal docs](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-package.html#library) which suggested adding a third component - an internal library (unfortunately not linkable, but search for "internal libraries"). If I understand the documentation correctly, I should be able to do something like this:

```
library foo-internal
  hs-source-dirs:    src
  build-depends:
                     base,
                     some-other-deps
  exposed-modules:
                     Data.Foo.Bar.Internal

library
  hs-source-dirs:    src
  build-depends:
                     base >= 4.9 && < 5,
                     foo-internal,
                     some-other-deps
  exposed-modules:
                     Data.Foo.Bar,
                     Data.Foo.Baz

test-suite test
  hs-source-dirs:
                     tests
  build-depends:
                     foo-library,
                     foo-internal
  other-modules:
                     Foo.Bar.Tests,
                     Foo.Baz.Tests
```

but running `stack build` here gives me warnings that `Data.Foo.Bar.Internal` "should be added to exposed-modules or other-modules in ./foo.cabal", and then a build error in the test that seems to be caused by failed unification (it points to a function argument for a function defined in the library, says that its type must be `Data.Foo.Bar.Internal.Qux` defined in package `foo`, and that the type `foo:Data.Foo.Bar.Internal.Qux` don't match).

**How can I expose internal modules to the test suite, without exposing them also to consumers of the library?**

Comment: Does it help if you move the `.hs` files of `foo-internal` to another `hs-source-dirs`, say, `src-internal`?

Comment: @danidiaz Possibly; I'm not sure I can do that, though, since it's not my project (and the main point here is to get a PR accepted) but I'll try it out locally to see if it helps.

Comment: @danidiaz: Yes, moving the files to a different root seems to work.

Comment: I've had the same problem, but I haven't found the exact place in the Cabal user guide that says that different libraries should have different source folders. https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-package.html?highlight=internal%20libraries#pkg-field-hs-source-dirs

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, different components (internal libraries, executables) should have modules under different roots.

- This is a recurrent point of confusion. For another example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6711739/6863749
- There is an open ticket on Cabal's issue tracker  about clarifying this with a suitable warning; it's apparently non-trivial to detect this situation reliably because it overlaps with legitimate use cases: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/5335